# Reading JSON file from url using ijson

Tags: python, urllib, ijson

This is the code that I have been trying:

```
import ijson
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen(some_link) as read_file:
        path_array = ijson.items(read_file, object_in_json)
```

but I get this error:

```
(b'lexical error: invalid char in json text.\n                                       \x1f\x8b\x08                     (right here) ------^\n',)
```

Comment: It seems like an error on the file thet it's being read. Can you post all or a portion of it? It may also be a character encoding error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably links are not supported by that library.

I advice you to use the `requests` module. So install it launching `pip install requests`.

Then, in your `.py` file:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url)
json = response.json()
```